# Storing JSON object into java String using Jackson api

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml

I have a requirement to deserialize Json object. **The fields of incoming Json can change dynamically** so I am thinking of storing it as a String. But not sure how to achieve this using Jackson. After deserializing the json I would want to access all the fields.

Incoming Json sample 1:

```
 {
    "NAME": "abs",
    "AGE": "25",
    "MARRIED": true,
}
```

Incoming Json sample 2:

```
 {
    "EMPLOYEE": true,
    "EMPLOYEEID": "123",
    "PERMANENT": true,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read them into a node tree like in the following example, where `input` is a string containing your json:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = om.readTree(input);
```

This allows you to access the fields of the json object dynamically, e.g.:

```
String name = node.path("NAME").asText();
```